# Change default style of a caption in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, caption

When inserting a figure or table, you can add a caption. It has some default styling that you can edit in the Quick Styles pane. By default in Word 2013 this is a 9pt italic font. Unfortunately, this makes the caption and the text itself italic, e.g.

> *Table 1 Income breakdown*

. My academic guidelines, however, indicate that captions should not be in italics, with exception of the enumeration of the figure or table. Some punctuation is necessary as well, e.g.

> *Table 1*. Income breakdown.

Is there any way this can be achieved in an automated manner?

Answer (score 12):

In home tab of your Word, right click on the arrow next to the styles shown in the image below

[image]

go to caption and select modify

[image]

you will see a window

[image]

in this area you can adjust font properties.

Comment: This changes the style of the label and the text, not of one of 'em.

Comment: Then why did you mark it as answered? This didn't answer your question.